# How to start tmux so that it won't get killed on exit in last windows?

Tags: command-line, tmux, session

I want to start tmux so that it won't quit when last pane/window is killed. As for now I do it  this way :

```
tmux new -d -s my_session_name
```

I can add a windows name as such:

```
tmux new -d -s my_session_name -n window_name
```

But it will still be killed on last windows kill. I would like to make it like permanent on this machine until somebody explicitly kills it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tmux option does what you want:

```
tmux set set-remain-on-exit on
```

Check out this U&L Q&A that asks the same question: [Prevent pane/window from closing when command completes - tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17116/prevent-pane-window-from-closing-when-command-completes-tmux)