# Kill a screen session when script is done executing

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a script that takes a while to run, and I'm using screen to run it.

```
ssh user@host screen -dm "python dostuff.py"
```

Now the question is, how do I make sure it kills the screen session after dostuff.py finishes execution? Whether it's because an error, or proper termination.

Comment: Having screen close is the default behavior I see, is yours staying open?

Comment: @EricRenouf yes, after the script finishes executing, I have to manually go back there, attach it back to my screen, and exit from it.

Comment: I also get a detached screen; even tried `screen -dm "ls;exit"`

Comment: @jeffSchaller I don't imagine you've found a solution to this?

Comment: What version of screen are you guys using?  I'm not able to recreate that, and all my quick searching turns out people trying to figure out how to prevent screen from terminating as soon as the command it's running finishes (e.g., [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157993/how-to-prevent-screen-from-terminating-once-process-ends) or [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47271/prevent-gnu-screen-from-terminating-session-once-executed-script-ends) or even [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224213/how-to-prevent-gnu-screen-from-clearing-the-screen-when-terminating)

Comment: Shelby, if you put 'python dostuff.py' into an executable shell script, then use screen to call that shell script, does it do what you want?

Comment: Unable to replicate @JeffSchaller's experiment.  `screen -S foo -dm "sleep 10"` followed by `screen -ls` will show a screen named `foo` for ten seconds; it then disappears.  Doing the same to invoke a python script that uses `time.sleep(10)` behaves the same- the screen is terminated when the script is completed.  This is with Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU).

Comment: @EricRenouf - looks like I have a pretty old version: 3.09.10 (4-Sep-01)

Comment: Ohh.. it may be because I have an old version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be in the "workaround" category, but I was able to achieve what I think your goal is by putting the command ("python dostuff.py" from your example) into a shell script, then running `... screen -d -m "/path/to/that/script"`

Version info:

```
$ screen -v
Screen version 3.09.10 (FAU) 4-Sep-01
```

Looks like I have a pretty old version of screen on this system! Perhaps screen's behavior changed in more recent versions to automatically exit?

```
$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /tmp/uscreens/S-username.
$ screen -dm "ls"
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        32112694.ls     (Detached)
1 Socket in /tmp/uscreens/S-username.
```

(screen -r; exit)

```
$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /tmp/uscreens/S-username.

$ cat runme
#!/bin/sh
sleep 6
ls > now

$ screen -d -m ./runme
$ ps -ef|grep sleep
 username 9633926  9437204   0 14:55:23  pts/1  0:00 grep sleep
 username 15532242 10223670   0 14:55:21  pts/6  0:00 sleep 6
```

(wait 6 seconds)

```
$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /tmp/uscreens/S-username.
$ ls now
now
```

One thing I realized when going through this was that my version of screen seemed to expect a session name after `-dm`; I had to separate `-d` and `-m` in order to pass a command argument.

Try using:

```
ssh user@host screen -d -m python dostuff.py
```

with an optional `-S` to name the session something specific.

Comment: Yup, turns out splitting -d and -m solved it for. That's weird.