# tmux: merge all windows as panes

Tags: tmux

I start GNU Parallel with --tmux which will start a tmux window per job.

I would like to join all windows as panes with the size nicely distributed between them (like tiled view: C-b M-5).

I tried doing:

```
seq 15 | parallel tmux -S /tmp/tmsF8j3K joinp -s {} -t 1
```

But it does not distribute the height evenly resulting in:

```
create pane failed: pane too small
```

Is there a way to tell a window to distribute height evenly when `joinp`ing or a way to join all windows as panes and then tile them? Maybe something using `select-layout tiled`?

**Edit**

I am using this as the test program:

```
seq 1000 | parallel --jobs 9 --tmux sleep
```

The goal is to have the 9 running jobs shown in a nice 3x3 window when attaching to tmux. When one job dies it should be replaced by the next job.

I have tried:

```
while [ -e "$SERVER" ] ; do
    top=$(tmux -S $SERVER new-window -P -n all)
    tmux -S $SERVER list-panes -a | grep -v "^$top" | cut -d':' -f1-2 |
        while read p ; do
          tmux -S $SERVER joinp -s $p -t $top
          tmux -S $SERVER select-layout tiled
        done
    tmux -S $SERVER kill-pane -t $top
    tmux -S $SERVER select-layout tiled
    sleep 1
done
```

But it still gives:

```
can't find pane X
```

And it does not keep all windows as panes in the first window when attaching.

Comment: Which `tmux` version are you using?  The `after-` hooks may help, but those aren't in the newest release yet.

Comment: I have 1.8, 1.9 and 2.1. Which one do you want me to use?

Comment: You would need [the dev version](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) to do this with hooks.

Comment: It turns out that "joinp" reorders the ids, so the output of list-panes is no longer valid.  I've edited my suggestion to use pane IDs.  There will be more than 3x3 with the `sleep` example because the dead jobs hang around for a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running a separate command, possibly in a loop, to move the panes after they've been created, you could extend the job command so that it moves its own pane at startup:

```
seq 1000 |
 parallel --jobs 9 --tmux tmux joinp -t :0 \; \
 tmux select-layout -t :0 tiled \; \
 sleep
```

This will show the additional tmux commands (and then their output, `arranging in: tiled`) in each pane.
To avoid that, you could write a wrapper script, eg.

```
#!/bin/sh

# move into the pane set
tmux joinp -t :0
tmux select-layout -t :0 tiled >/dev/null

# start the real task
sleep "$@"
```

And then run

```
seq 1000 | parallel --tmux --jobs 9 /path/to/wrapper.sh
```

Comment: See --tmuxpane in next release of GNU Parallel :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `select-layout` suggestion is along the right track, but needs to be invoked after each new pane is created.  All panes are immediately reorganised, so (in my test -- a 95x58 terminal) there's enough room for the next split.

To avoid the `can't join a pane to its own window` message, it helps to create an additional window, then move all the existing windows into that, and terminate the extra pane at the end.  `parallel` is not the right tool for this - you'd be better off querying the running windows, and moving each one, in a loop:

```
top=$(tmux -S $SERVER new-window -P -n all)
tmux -S $SERVER list-panes -a | grep -v "^$top" | grep -o  "%[0-9]\+\>" | 
  while read p ; do 
    tmux -S $SERVER joinp -s $p -t $top
    tmux -S $SERVER select-layout tiled
  done
tmux -S $SERVER kill-pane -t $top
tmux -S $SERVER select-layout tiled
```

Alternatively, you could make each new pane 1 line high, with `joinp -l 1`.  Depending on the size of your terminal, this might be enough to only need the one `select-layout` at the end.

However, `parallel` doesn't keep track of existing `tmux` windows/panes, and simply starts each job in a new window.  The old one may disappear, depending on the [remain-on-exit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17121/90751) setting.  So after a while, the original window (which showed each job in a pane) will contain no running jobs, and all the new jobs will be in their own windows again.  You will have to rerun the script to move all the windows (and any old panes) into a single window again.

Comment: I cannot make your solution work on: seq 1000 | parallel --tmux sleep

Comment: @OleTange `seq ... | parallel ... sleep` will mean parallel jobs `sleep 1`, `sleep 2`, `sleep 3` etc., so the first few will probably exit before you run all the `joinp`.  And with 1000, you may still reach `pane too small`.

Comment: It will only run one per CPU in parallel. How can I make the panes show the currently running jobs? So a pane is replace with the next job when one pane finishes.